# Finding duplicates in all columns with varying row numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and was trying to write a macro to check duplicates among a column. I have values in columns from A to Z with varying last row number, some may be 5 while  some may be 10. Is there any way to check if duplicate value exist among a column and then print "duplicate" on the first row (I dont have any values in the first row for all the columns). I need this for varying last row and last column number.

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far, and what specific error are you getting? Have a read of [ask], then [edit] your question, please.

Comment: @Olly I have found the last column number and last row number for each of the individual columns. I am facing it difficult to find duplicates among a single column and then iterate it for all other columns.

Comment: Once more: please [edit] your question to show your code: show what works, and what you have tried that doesn't work.

Comment: How would you do it using a formula or using the Excel interface?  `countif` and/or `Find` ?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, If you have it to make the check on column A, you can use the formula ==IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>=1,"Duplicate","No Duplicate")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Get_Unique_Count_Paste_Array()

    Dim Ob As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim Item As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For i = 1 To 26

            Set Ob = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

            LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row

            For Each rng In .Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(LR, i))
                str = Trim(rng.Value)
                If Len(str) > 0 Then
                    Ob(str) = Ob(str) + 1
                End If
            Next rng

            For Each Item In Ob.keys

               If .Cells(1, i).Value = "" Then
                   .Cells(1, i).Value = Item

               ElseIf .Cells(1, i).Value <> "" Then
                   .Cells(1, i).Value = .Cells(1, i).Value & ", " & Item
               End If

            Next Item

        Next i

    End With

  End Sub
```

Edited Version:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Get_Unique_Count_Paste_Array()

    Dim Ob As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim Item As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For i = 1 To 26

            Set Ob = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

            LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row

            For Each rng In .Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(LR, i))
                str = Trim(rng.Value)
                If Len(str) > 0 Then
                    Ob(str) = Ob(str) + 1
                End If
            Next rng

            For Each Item In Ob.keys

               If .Cells(1, i).Value = "" And Ob(Item) > 1 Then
                    .Cells(1, i).Value = "Duplicate"
                    Exit For
               End If

            Next Item

        Next i

    End With

  End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, the above programs prints all the unique value among row element into the respective first row. All I needed was to check and flag as 1 & 0 if there are duplicate elements among row elements in a column. But this was a great learning opportunity .

Comment: Dear @sam glad to hear that your satisfied with the code.Please evaluated the edited version and provide a feedback :)

Comment: This was so useful.. You are the real MVP :)

Answer (score 0):

A slight alteration of @error 1004's idea

```
Private d As Scripting.Dictionary
Private s As String

Function Get_Dupe_Summary(rngInput As Excel.Range) as string

Dim c As Excel.Range

    Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For Each c In rngInput.Cells
        If d.Exists(c.Value) Then
            Get_Dupe_Summary = Get_Dupe_Summary & _
                IIf(Len(Get_Dupe_Summary) > 0, ",", "") & _
                "Dupe : " & c & " on row " & c.Row
        Else
            d.Add c.Value, 1
        End If
    Next c

End Function
```